# pipenv modules not seen by Django manage.py

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pipenv

I just started working on a Django project. For virtual environment I am trying to use pipenv.

Inside my working directory;

First I created a virtualenv with

**$ pipenv install django

$ pipenv install autoslug**

then activated it with

**$ pipenv shell**

After that, I started a Django project with

**$ django-admin startproject x**

Then I started an app within the project with

**$ django-admin startapp y**

Inside app y, I imported module "autoslug".

I installed autoslug with

**$pipenv install django-autoslug**

When I try to make migrations with

**$ python manage.py makemigrations**

It gives an error

***no module named autoslug***

My virtualenv is activated and the module is installed inside it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be running the python executable of your virtual environment.
Using pipenv, the command should be `pipenv run python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: I just solved the issue. I somehow had two Pythons installed and created an alias that results in pointing to a Python interpreter outside the virtualenv.

I removed the alias and now it works perfectly.